# Django - How to Authenticate users while logging in (or) registering while using django-bootstrap-toolkit?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to authenticate a user(using the simple authenticate() function) in django.

```
def auth(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        auth_form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if auth_form.is_valid():
            auth_form.save()
            user = authenticate(username=request.POST['id_username'],password=request.POST['id_password'])
            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                return redirect('/profile/home/')
            else:
                return redirect('/')
    else:
        return redirect('/')

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SimpleUserCreation(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            user = authenticate(username=request.POST['id_username'],password=request.POST['id_password1'])
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('/profile/home/')
        else:
            return redirect('/')
```

This is the template displaying the forms - Just wanted to display login and register forms in the same page(for this example)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load bootstrap_toolkit %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4 offset1 login">
            <form class="form-signin" action="/auth/" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ auth_form|as_bootstrap }}
                <br>
                <center>
                    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">
                        Sign In
                    </button>
                </center>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="span4 offset2 signup">
            <form action="/register/" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|as_bootstrap }}
                <br>
                <center>
                    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">
                        Register
                    </button>
                </center>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I am getting an error like this:

```
ValueError at /auth/
The view SimpleUserAuth.auth.views.auth didn't return an HttpResponse object.
```

Any idea where i am going wrong?? I think its the authenticating function's inability to find the correct id for the fields...maybe i am wrong. I am a Noob :|

Cheers

Comment: Please post also your urlconf. It seems that you are not using your view in the urls.py file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `auth` method, if `auth_form.is_valid()` returns `False`, you do not return a `response` object.

The same is the case in `def register(request):` . If it is a `GET` request, the method does not return a `response` object.

Hence the error(s)

Comment: but when i tried without bootstrap-toolkit, it worked fine...i mean the is_valid() methods for both the forms. Am i looking at something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I made the mistake in these lines -

1) AuthenticationForm takes argument as follows:
AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)

2) u can't save AuthenticationForm.

```
auth_form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if auth_form.is_valid():
            auth_form.save()
```

Thanks for the help karthik :)